# Modificando items en un canvas con Python y Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Estoy empezando a aprender programación con Python y usando Tkinter. Quiero pintar un tablero de casillas (parecido a uno de ajedrez pero de dimensiones 16x16) y quiero que al hacer clic en una de las casillas se le cambie el color. Estoy identificando cada casilla con un tag que es la fila/columna (p.ejemplo: 0712). Después quiero acceder a la casilla donde he hecho clic usando ese tag y con find_withtag(). Pero algo debo estar haciendo mal porque en muchos casos no consigo que me devuelva un handle o el que me devuelve corresponde a otra casilla. Ahí va algo parecido al código que uso. Cualquier ayuda para ver qué estoy haciendo mal(que seguro es un error de principiante) es bienvenida.

```
    # vamos a pintar un tablero de 16x16 rectángulos

    for r in range(self.filas):
        for c in range(self.columnas):
    ...
    ...

            # r+1 nos da el númro de la fila (de 1 a 16)
            # c+1 nos da el número de la columna (de 1 a 16)
            id_casilla = str(r+1).zfill(2) +  str(c+1).zfill(2)
            print('Id de la casilla:', id_casilla)              
            self.el_tablero.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2,  fill=self.color_casillas, tags=id_casilla)
...

# Más tarde quiero modificar el color del rectagulo donde haga clic con el ratón
# Quiero acceder a cada rectángulo según su tag de id_casilla

    # Si llegamos aquí es que se ha hecho clic dentro del tablero

    columna = int((event.x - self.dim_borde) / self.dim_casilla) + 1
    fila = int((event.y - self.dim_borde) / self.dim_casilla) + 1
    id_casilla =  str(fila).zfill(2) +  str(columna).zfill(2)
    handle_casilla = self.el_tablero.find_withtag(tag_id_casilla)

    self.el_tablero.itemconfig(handle_casilla, fill='blue')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu error está en no estar formando tags correctas, la razón es que hay dos métodos par identificar un item:

- `Item handles`: son valores enteros que identifican a cada item. Son asignados automáticamente y pueden ser pasados a los diferentes métodos tanto como enteros como cadenas.
- `Tags`: son cadenas asociadas a los items, pueden contener cualquier carácter menos espacios. Nunca deben asemejarse a un "item handler" o **serán confundidas por ellos cuando las pases a los métodos**.

Una forma algo más robusta de generar tus tags podría ser:

> ```
> 01|01
> 01|02
> ...
> ```

o

> ```
> #0101
> #0102
> ...
> ```

En vez de:

> ```
> 0101
> 0202
> ...
> ```

que son similares a los items handles.

```
import tkinter as tk


class Test(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.filas = 16
        self.columnas = 16
        self.dim_casilla = 50
        self.color_casillas = "green"
        self.dim_borde=0
        self.el_tablero = tk.Canvas(
            width=self.filas * self.dim_casilla,
            height=self.columnas * self.dim_casilla
            )

        self.el_tablero.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        self.fill_board()
        self.el_tablero.bind("<Button-1>", self.on_board_click)

    def fill_board(self):
        # vamos a pintar un tablero de 16x16 rectángulos
        for r in range(self.filas):
            for c in range(self.columnas):
                id_casilla = (
                    f"{r + 1:0{len(str(self.filas))}d}|"
                    f"{c + 1:0{len(str(self.columnas))}d}")
                x1, y1 = c * self.dim_casilla, r * self.dim_casilla
                x2, y2 = x1 + self.dim_casilla, y1 + self.dim_casilla 
                self.el_tablero.create_rectangle(
                    x1, y1, x2, y2,
                    fill=self.color_casillas,
                    tags=id_casilla
                    )

    def on_board_click(self, event):
        columna = (event.x - self.dim_borde) // self.dim_casilla
        fila = (event.y - self.dim_borde) // self.dim_casilla
        id_casilla = (
            f"{fila + 1:0{len(str(self.filas))}d}|"
            f"{columna + 1:0{len(str(self.columnas))}d}")
        self.el_tablero.itemconfig(id_casilla, fill='blue')



if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Test(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Una forma muy simple de obtener la casilla en la que se hace click es usar `tkinter.Canvas.find_withtag` pero usando simplemente `tk.CURRENT` como argumento, en vez de tener que calcular las coordenadas manualmente:

```
import tkinter as tk


class Test(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.filas = 16
        self.columnas = 16
        self.dim_casilla = 50
        self.color_casillas = "green"
        self.el_tablero = tk.Canvas(
            width=self.filas * self.dim_casilla,
            height=self.columnas * self.dim_casilla
            )

        self.el_tablero.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        self.fill_board()
        self.el_tablero.bind("<Button-1>", self.on_board_click)

    def fill_board(self):
        # vamos a pintar un tablero de 16x16 rectángulos
        for r in range(self.filas):
            for c in range(self.columnas):
                id_casilla = str(r + 1).zfill(2) +  str(c + 1).zfill(2)
                x1, y1 = c * self.dim_casilla, r * self.dim_casilla
                x2, y2 = x1 + self.dim_casilla, y1 + self.dim_casilla 
                self.el_tablero.create_rectangle(
                    x1, y1, x2, y2,
                    fill=self.color_casillas,
                    tags=id_casilla
                    )

    def on_board_click(self, event):
        if event.widget.find_withtag(tk.CURRENT):
            event.widget.itemconfig(tk.CURRENT, fill="blue")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Test(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]